# Update Select When New Category Added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

hi guys i want to update select options when user add new category can anyone tell me how to do this ?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import cat from '../Category.json'
function AddProdocts() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("New Category Added");
    }, [cat]);
    return (
        <div className='mx-auto w-50 border  p-4 rounded-4 mt-4 '>
            <form action="">
                <div className='mb-3 row align-self-center'>
                    <label htmlFor="price" className='form-label cols '>Category: </label>
                    <select id="" className="form-select col ms-2">
                        {cat.map((value, i) => <option key={i}>{value}</option>)}
                    </select>
                    <button type='button' className='btn btn-success col-auto text-center' onClick={() => {
                        let newCategory = prompt("Please enter your new Category");
                        newCategory && //check if newCategory isnt empty
                            cat.push(newCategory) // push data inside your json file 
                    }}>+</button>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

i want to update option with new item added in this part of code

```
<select id="" className="form-select col ms-2">
{cat.map((value, i) => <option key={i}>{value}</option>)}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want React re-render your component when new category added, add local state to it.
Here is the updated code:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import cat from '../Category.json'
function AddProdocts() {
    // New code
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState(cat)
    return (
        <div className='mx-auto w-50 border  p-4 rounded-4 mt-4 '>
            <form action="">
                <div className='mb-3 row align-self-center'>
                    <label htmlFor="price" className='form-label cols '>Category: </label>
                    <select id="" className="form-select col ms-2">
                        {categories.map((value, i) => <option key={i}>{value}</option>)}
                    </select>
                    <button type='button' className='btn btn-success col-auto text-center' onClick={() => {
                   let newCategory = prompt("Please enter your new Category");
                    // New code
                    if(newCategory) {
                      setCategories(prev => [...prev, newCategory])
                     }
                    }}>+</button>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks this work but this work too i found it my self in internet

Comment: import React from "react";

function Home() {

  const [value,setValue] = useState();

  const refresh = ()=>{
      // it re-renders the component     setValue({});
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{Math.random()}</p>
      <button onClick={refresh}>Refresh component</button>
    </div>
  );
}